# Rest FB Api Find Email id and list of friends Of User

Tags: java, restfb

I am using RestFb api, I am able to retrive the page likes, but I am not able to retrives the list of users who liked the page. As well as I am not able to find the List of friends of a particular **User** using My appId and appSecret.